# Splitting and returning part of a string

Tags: javascript

I have two strings such as:

```
sometext~somemoretext~extratext
```

and

```
sometext~otherextratext
```

I wish to crop off the last tilde (~) and all text to the right.  For instance, the above two strings would result in:

```
sometext~somemoretext
```

and

```
sometext
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you even try anything? This seems rather trivial.

Comment: I had tried using split() before asking this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `lastIndexOf(char)` returns the position of the last found occurrence of a specified value in a string
- `substring(from, to)` extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string

For instance:

```
var txt = 'sometext~somemoretext~extratext';
txt = txt.substring(0, txt.lastIndexOf('~'));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/tXs8s/)**

**I strongly suggest you to read the doc on the [Javascript String Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)**

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of lastIndexOf.  I have since been reading Javascript String Object.

Answer (score 4):

```
return theString.replace(/~[^~]*$/, '');
```

Comment: regular expressions seem to be a bit overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a regular expression with the [`.replace()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
var str = 'sometext~somemoretext~extratext';
str = str.replace(/~[\w\s]+$/, '');
```

Here is a jsFiddle of the above code for you to run: http://jsfiddle.net/NELFB/

Answer (score 1):

you can use substr to split the string, then rebuild them for what ever you need

```
var someString = "sometext~otherextratext";
someString = someString.split('~');
```

this will give you an array, which you can use like someString[0];

use .replace('~', '') if you need to further remove the ones at the end of strings

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
function removeExtra(input){
    return input.substr(0,input.lastIndexOf('~'))
}
```